# Packet sniffing in c under window OS

Tags: c, windows, network-programming

I want to sniff network packets without wincap library, kindly give me some hints or direction so that I can make it possible.

Comment: You mean winpcap library, aye? Even Cygwin related TCPDump tools require it. I don't know of any that don't use it. Why do you need to avoid it?

Comment: Only the window API which I have to use.

Comment: It's an open source project, so you can download the source and see what it's doing.  Of course, if you spend a lot of time looking at winpcap source to try to replicate what winpcap does, you might as well just use it. http://www.winpcap.org/install/bin/WpcapSrc_4_1_2.zip

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You know, libpcap exists for a reason: It does something that's necessary.

You need to set up a system-level hook for TCP/IP events, and the way global hooks work means you need to do this from a DLL.

Having hooked those events, you have to figure out the contents of the packets you get.

Are you sure you want to re-invent this wheel?

I found some introductory info on hooking Windows events [here](http://www.sdn.nl/SDN/Artikelen/tabid/58/view/View/ArticleID/2187/Hooks-and-Sockets-the-Low-Side-of-VO.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could start to do kernel level programming and catch there the packets. This is for sure complicated but you'll learn much.

Comment: Catching packets using netfilter hooks in the kernel is a pain.
Catching packets in a huge sized, non documented and closed kernel as the Microsoft one is shooting yourself in a foot.
IMHO of course.